# Need Only One URL for the subdomain of the website

Tags: subdomain, web-hosting

I have a subdomain named blog so i usually access by blog.mydomain.com

but can also accessed by the url mydomain.com/blog. I don't want this url to be used and how can i prevent it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can prevent that url i.e**(mydomain.com/blog)** is to redirect it using *.htaccess* to the subdomain.